# Regression models with special categorical variables

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, categorical-data, polynomial

I need to build a regression model. I have 3 features: x1, x2, x3.
Based on those 3 features I want to predict 3 dependent variables: y1, y2, y3.
So far I created 3 separate models (Polynomial regression) based on the same features with different output variables.

But additionally I have 3 categorical features (x4, x5, x6) which tell about the ratio of those 3 dependent variables to each other, for example: x4=3, x5=1 x6=2 (ratio 3:1:2) which means that y1 should have the biggest value, y2 smallest and y1 medium value. So those categorical features can improve results of those 3 models.

1. What is the best type of model to use those categorical features?
2. Should I build 3 models and final 1 that is using those categorical
   features or should I build 1 general model that includes everything?
3. Can I build maybe some simple neural network with additional nodes
   that are somehow increasing one of the output variables when a
   specific categorical feature is high and decrease it when it’s low? Or create some custom loss function?

PS. The type of problem is rather convex.

Comment: Are the ratios meant to be exact, or also subject to noise?

Comment: One easy and probably suboptimal approach: just model $y_1\sim x_1,x_2,x_3$, then $y_2\approx \hat{y}_1 \cdot x_5 / x_4$ and $y_3\approx \hat{y}_1 \cdot x_6 / x_4$.

Comment: @BenReiniger Thank you for your reply, that seems to be a good idea. Yes, they are also subject to noise.